# Find numerical minimum of a function with many parameters

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I have a function

$$f(\vec{r}_1\dots,\vec{r}_N)=\mathrm{The \ sum\ of\ square roots\ of\ the \  eigenvalues\ of\ }\Omega(\vec{r}_1\dots,\vec{r}_N)$$

And I want to find one of its local minima with respect to $\vec{r}_1\dots,\vec{r}_N)$. Here $N$ could be amount to ~10000. As the algorithm of calculating eigenvalues costs $O(N^3)$, it can be quite time-consuming to calculate $f$ for a set of $\{\vec{r}_1\dots,\vec{r}_N\}$ even if I used clusters. But the good thing is, I already have good initial values for $\vec{r}_1\dots,\vec{r}_N$
 so they are already pretty close to the mimimum.

So what's the fastest way to find the mimimum in this scenario?

Comment: Take a look at [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29).

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for the tip! But I actually made a mistake in the description, so the trace won't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably Limited Memory Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno algorithm as it is a very general algoritm for optimization that takes very little function calls, if you can calculate the first derivative analytically. If you cannot, you will have to calculate the first derivatvie numerically which is hard, but in this case lBFGS is probably still a very good choice.